# How to provide login credentials for app review?

Tags: google-play-console

I had made a messenger app with calls and chat (which asks phonenumber and a One Time Password)
I had uploaded it to the play store but the error was, that it requires **Login Credentials.** I have given a dummy PhoneNumber. But, I dont know how to give One Time Password(OTP).

Please help me with this.

Thank you..